# How to merge mutidimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here I have `data.payload` and `folderObjs` I want to merge `data.payload` in `folderObjs` inside which `folderObjs`'s  `folderid == data.payload[i].upperfolderid` see `patternObj` console that type result I want

I tried using concat but it merge in `folderObjs` array not merge inside specific `folderObjs` `folderid`

```
data.payload
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 0: { folderid: 903, folderName: "f11", upperfolderid: 899} 
 1: { folderid: 904, folderName: "f22", upperfolderid: 899}

folderObjs
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 0: { folderid: 899, folderName: "f1", upperfolderid: 122}
 1: { folderid: 900, folderName: "f2", upperfolderid: 122}
 2: { folderid: 901, folderName: "f3", upperfolderid: 122}
 3: { folderid: 902, folderName: "f4", upperfolderid: 122}

 // TS

 folderObjs : Folder[] = [];
 patternObj : Pattern[] = [];

 this.patterObj = this.folderObjs.concat(data.payload);
 console.log(this.patternObj);

 // This type result I want
 0: {folderid: 899, folderName: "f1,upperfolderid: 122,
  {0: {folderid: 903, folderName: "f11", upperfolderid: 899} 
   1: {folderid: 904, folderName: "f22", upperfolderid: 899}
  }
 }
 1: {folderid: 900, folderName: "f2",upperfolderid: 122}
 2: {folderid: 901, folderName: "f3",upperfolderid: 122}
 3: {folderid: 902, folderName: "f4",upperfolderid: 122}
```

Comment: Hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below example will help.

```
const result = this.folderObjs.map(val => {
  return Object.assign({}, val, this.payload.filter(v => v.upperfolderid === val.folderid));
});
console.log(result);
```